# Preferentially gluing lists on recursion--Single point of return

Tags: recursion, lisp, common-lisp

Warning:  Absolute Lisp n00b.  I'm very well versed in Java, and moderately in C.  Lisp... so far hasn't been my favorite.  (But its better than prolog...)

I want to iterate through a list and preferentially return a subset of that list.

I've successfully wrote code that will tear apart the list and rebuild it as the stack unwinds using the (append ) function.  However, when I try to throw in conditions I get significant trouble.

```
(defun split-then-rebuild-list (row value llist)
   (cond ((not (eq llist nil))
          (let ((item (first llist))
                (rval nil))
            (print llist)
            (print "Entering next recursion level")
            (setf rval (split-then-rebuild-list row value (cdr llist)))
            (print "Left recursion")
            (print "Current item: ")
            (princ item)
            (print "Received: ")
            (Princ rval)
            (print "Appended:")
            (setf x (first(first item)))
            (and (eq row x) (eq value (nth 2 (first item)))
                 (print "gluing: ")
                 (princ rval)
                 (princ item)
                 (setf rval (append rval item )))))))
```

NIL just keeps getting returned right up the stack as it unwinds.  What I don't understand is why when I type `(set tmp (list A B C) )` then `(append tmp nil)` it returns `(A B C)` but not in the code as I have it here.  To me, I would read this in a way that would say " return nil in all cases but a list under these conditions.  If two list items met the condition, they would be appended otherwise it should just return the list from the previous recursion level.

[EDITED] to provide additional information.
My original function that works just fine for breaking apart and rebuilding:

```
(defun splitThenRebuildList( llist )
        (cond(
        (not (eq llist nil ))
        (let(
        (item (first llist))
        (rval)
        );end let decl
        (print llist )
        (setf rval (splitThenRebuildList( cdr llist )))
        (print "item: ")(princ item)
        (print "Received: ") (Princ rval)
        (append rval item )
        );end let
        ));end cond
)
```

Any suggestions to modify this to get what I need since the first posted code is an abortion?

Comment: What is that code supposed to do?

Comment: maybe you can format the code to Lisp conventions with indentation?

Comment: where does the variable X come from?

Comment: `(and ... (princ rval) (princ item) ...)` returns `NIL` if `rval` or `item` is `NIL`, which may explain why your function keeps returning `NIL`.

Comment: @danlei the code is supposed to recurse a list until empty and then glue individual items together based on arbitrary parameters.

Comment: @Ranier 
1.  I have one weekend to learn Lisp.  No time to learn beautification.  Ignore my question if it bothers you.  
2.  I'm running on Clisp.
3.  It's declared exactly where written.  Are inline declarations bad?

Comment: Consider using `let` to bind `x` as a local variable, instead of `setf`.

Comment: I switched to `let`, but then it complained about x not being assigned a value.

Comment: You may benefit from studying how to flatten a list in Lisp. It is a related task. There are plenty of examples available.

Comment: PS: Rainer is right, intending the code according to Lisp conventions will help. Take a moment to compare your original to the edits by danlei.

Comment: I thank Rainer for the edits, but if there's a fatal flaw, the beautification didn't make it more apparent.  Searching google about list flattening in lisp.

Comment: Delete `(princ rval)` and `(princ item)` as they're likely troublemakers (see comment above).

Comment: I can't tell from the question: are you avoiding the built-in functions and using recursion because you don't know any better, or because you want to do everything the hard way to learn?  You can't learn very much of a programming language in a weekend, so personally I'd probably try to stick with high-level idiomatic approaches, not Java-in-different-syntax.

Comment: If your print-out calls are there primarily for debugging purposes, you may want to have a look at TRACE.

Comment: Writing Lisp code without proper indentation is 100% doomed to fail. No, I did not edit your code. X is never declared anywhere. You should want to do that.

Comment: You should really be more specific what you're trying to do. From your own remarks that you're trying to learn Lisp in very short time and your code example, I can only infer that your solution is much more complicated than it needs to be. The simple solution for selecting list elements fulfilling some condition is `remove-if-not`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the comments to your question, I've suggested `remove-if-not`. Here's an example using it that does what I guess your own function tries to do, too. Is this what you intend or not?

```
(defun filter-by-row-and-value (row value seq)
  (remove-if-not (lambda (x)
                   (and (eql row (first x))
                        (eql value (third x))))
                 seq
                 :key #'first))
```

As others have already noted, the reason your own code doesn't what you expect is probably that you've put debugging output statements inside the `and` form. For that specific case, I'ld suggest using

```
(when (and conditions...)
  debugging-output
  return-value)
```

instead of

```
(and conditions...
     debugging-output
     return-value)
```

Comment: Thank you much, your ideas have clarified some of my errors.  Most of what was tripping me up so far was not correctly understanding how `cond` worked in relationship to the traditional if/else control flows I'm used  to.

Answer (score 0):

It's really hard to tell what you're trying to do.  Here's an example of what you *might* be trying to do.

This is a function which takes a value and a list, and returns the subset of the list whose elements are a cons pair whose car is `eq` to `3`.  You can make the test more complicated if you want.

```
(defun do-something-to-list (value list)
  (cond ((null list)
     nil)
    ((eq value (first (first list)))
     (cons (first list)
       (do-something-to-list value (rest list))))
    (t
     (do-something-to-list value (rest list)))))
```

In action:

```
(do-something-to-list 3 '((3 9) (a b c) (47 3) (3 zztop) (blah)))
((3 9) (3 zztop))
```

Note: there are various ways to do this kind of thing using built-in routines in common-lisp, but it looks like you're just trying to learn how to understand recursion.

Comment: You're right, I'm not used to languages that force recursion, and my experiences in industry using Java tend to push you away from ever using the technique.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove `(princ rval)` and `(princ item)` from the code, the function works, sort of.

```
(split-then-rebuild-list :a 4 '(((:a nil 4))((:b nil 5))))
```

=>
((:A NIL 4))

To rebuild the list as the recursion unwinds, return a value when the test for a matching item is false.